# mplayer command line only show timestamp

Tags: mplayer

I want to use mplayer command line to play music files in the terminal and keep the output messages quiet only except for audio timestamp. Only keep the last line `A: 133.5 (02:13.4) of 347.1 (05:47.0)  0.` in the below example (of course 02:13.4/05:47.0 format would be better). Is there any way to get that? Thanks.

```
> mplayer -novideo "Tokimeki Records,ひかり/Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり)/Tokimeki Records,ひかり - Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり).flac"
MPlayer 1.5-14.0.0 (C) 2000-2022 MPlayer Team
Can't init Apple Remote.

Playing Tokimeki Records,ひかり/Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり)/Tokimeki Records,ひかり - Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり).flac.
libavformat version 59.17.102 (internal)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: audio (flac), -aid 0
[lavf] stream 1: video (mjpeg), -vid 0
Clip info:
 ALBUM: Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり)
 ARTIST: Tokimeki Records/ひかり
 COMMENT: Create by xxxx copyright protected dump tool. author 5L
 TITLE: Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり)
Load subtitles in Tokimeki Records,ひかり/Midnight Pretenders (feat. ひかり)/
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 59.21.100 (internal)
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 0.0 kbit/0.00% (ratio: 0->192000)
Selected audio codec: [ffflac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg FLAC audio)
==========================================================================
AO: [coreaudio] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
A: 133.5 (02:13.4) of 347.1 (05:47.0)  0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by disabling verbosity for all modules and enabling it only for `STATUSLINE`

```
mplayer -novideo -msglevel all=0:statusline=5 infile.mp4
```

The `-msglevel` option is explained in the manual:

> `-msglevel <all=<level>:<module>=<level>:...>`
> Control verbosity directly for each module.  The 'all' module changes the verbosity of all the modules not explicitly specified on
> the command line.  See `-msglevel help` for a list of all modules.
> NOTE:  Some  messages  are  printed  before  the command line is parsed and are therefore not affected by `-msglevel`.  To control these
> messages you have to use the `MPLAYER_VERBOSE` environment variable.
> Available levels:
> -1   complete silence
> 0   fatal messages only
> 1   error messages
> 2   warning messages
> 3   short hints
> 4   informational messages
> 5   status messages (default)
> 6   verbose messages
> 7   debug level 2
> 8   debug level 3
> 9   debug level 4

Or, you could use [`mpv`](https://mpv.io/) which has similar switches and prints elapsed/total times just like you want:

```
mpv --no-video --msg-level=all=no,statusline=status infile.mp4
```